# How to convert a string expression to vb code?

Tags: vb.net

I have a string output from user interface as below,

```
strFormula ="gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C1").value *
               gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C2").value"
```

if i write code like

```
 dblRes=gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * 
            gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C2").value
```

it will give result.. but since its a string i could not get result

How can I remove the double quotes from the above string and get the values entered in the grid cells to be multiplied?

Comment: The need for this is usually the result of a design flaw.

Comment: Are you saying that the user has input that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys thanks for your updates.. I wrote my own function by using your concepts and some other code snippets .I am posting the result

```
Function generate(ByVal alg As String, ByVal intRow As Integer) As String Dim algSplit As String() = alg.Split(" "c)

    For index As Int32 = 0 To algSplit.Length - 1
        'algSplit(index) = algSplit(index).Replace("#"c, "Number")
        If algSplit(index).Contains("[") Then
            Dim i As Integer = algSplit(index).IndexOf("[")
            Dim f As String = algSplit(index).Substring(i + 1, algSplit(index).IndexOf("]", i + 1) - i - 1)
            Dim grdCell As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridCell = dgExcelEstimate.Rows(intRow).Cells(f)
            Dim dblVal As Double = grdCell.Value
            algSplit(index) = dblVal
        End If

    Next

    Dim result As String = String.Join("", algSplit)
    'Dim dblRes As Double = Convert.ToDouble(result)
    Return result
End Function
```

Thanks again every one.. expecting same in future

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an 'easy' way to do this, since VB.Net doesn't have an "eval()" like some other languages. However, it does support run-time compilation. Here are a couple articles which may help you:

- [Using .NET Languages to make your Application Scriptable](http://www.divelements.co.uk/net/articles/plugins/scripting.asp) (VB.Net example)
- [Runtime Compilation (A .NET eval statement)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3445/Runtime-Compilation-A-NET-eval-statement) (C# example)

Both are intended to be a bit more robust than just executing single lines of code, allowing users to input entire textboxes of their own code for example, but should give you some direction. Both include sample projects.